# Understanding Universal Kriging results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kriging

The results obtained using the Universal Kriging method with 41 data points appear as shown in the graph. I would like to inquire about the reasons behind the occurrence of the sawtooth pattern in the graph and whether such results are normal. Version used: ArcMap 10.5.

The text below contains the supplementary information I've added along with the point I would like to inquire about (highlighted in a red circle). The interpolated values are represented by the "rm" row.

Here is my file.

```
FID,twd97_x,twd97_y,rm
0,251889,2677570,26573
1,238507,2672568,28075
2,242878,2675279,25546
3,244498,2685943,33287
4,274747,2682464,12547
5,231737,2662929,26841
6,252700,2686109,37222
7,250569,2684215,38413
8,233861,2679561,28407
9,234598,2675075,19666
10,232929,2672818,30424
11,234225,2650821,31086
12,264383,2627763,5120
13,263296,2657098,17384
14,249338,2638343,31362
15,235137,2636434,22399
16,235814,2661883,22775
17,237260,2653410,24431
18,250702,2646682,25386
19,258960,2627836,8333
20,241644,2650461,21990
21,277694,2670940,20687
22,277811,2668493,7909
23,255345,2645420,20648
24,237790,2666334,22755
25,249461,2669020,31190
26,244844,2632153,38543
27,250458,2657114,36122
28,245156,2651954,20761
29,246238,2663981,19417
30,242781,2644059,22608
31,268178,2649839,15961
32,257743,2653572,24265
33,268652,2668755,16239
34,263463,2652801,19697
35,270860,2667163,17061
36,273020,2676414,20472
37,234422,2644553,31352
38,236904,2630663,21315
39,229870,2651436,18303
40,268492,2658732,16010
41,230863,2647736,29789
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a mess, but impossible to tell what's going on without more details of your model or map. Kriged predictions should be a smooth interpolation in continuous space, but if you've predicted on a small grid and then tried to make contours then maybe you get these jagged edges? Impossible to say without more detail, like the values at the locations or a legend for the prediction surface,

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. What I meant was the fragmented edges observed in the results obtained after using the Universal Kriging method. I would like to ask why this phenomenon is occurring. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Could you post your data either as text (comma separated) within the question (41 lines of text is acceptible, if this was 400 lines then don't) and not as an image? Or share the shapefile or whatever. Also, you should show in your Q all the parameters and setting you may have given to the kriging tool, and any other output it gives - I'm not familiar with ArcMap's kriging module so I don't know what you've asked of it and exactly what its told you in return - are there any messages, infos, warnings etc?

Comment: ArcMap did not provide any warnings; it completed universal kriging without issuing any alerts. However, I'm curious about the serrated patterns in the results (highlighted in red circles). How are these patterns generated, and is this considered normal? Once again, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I *think* that the "Variable search radius" with such a small number of points in your data means that these odd artefacts get created because some aspect of the kriging estimation is getting cut off. What happens if you don't have a variable search radius? There's no reason why it can't use all the data, it shouldn't be slow.